# Django how to filter ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to build a form with filtered many-to-many field.
so i created Objects:

**Dayname**

1) name=sunday

2) name=monday

**Submain**

1) name:Math

days(ManytoMany field): Sunday Monday

2) name: Sport

days(ManytoMany field): Tuesday

3) name:Dance

days(ManytoMany field): Sunday Tuesday

**Day**

1)name(Char field)="Sunday"

hog1(ManytoMany field, filterd): will show me only **Dance** and **Math** to pick.

how can i filted this hog1 manytomany field in the form.py ?
should i change the Name of Day model into forginkey of dayname?
thank you for any help.

I Have 3 Models:

**Models.py**

```
class Dayname(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(verbose_name="day", max_length=200, null=True)
 def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Submain(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(verbose_name="שם החוג", max_length=200, null=True)
 days = models.ManyToManyField(Dayname, verbose_name="ימי פעילות", 
 related_name="active", max_length=200, null=True,
                              )

def __str__(self):
    return self.name




class Day(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(verbose_name="יום", max_length=200, null=True)
  hog2 = models.ManyToManyField(Submain, verbose_name="חוג 2 ביום", 
     related_name="hog2", max_length=200, null=True,
                              )

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class DaysForm(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DaysForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['hog1'].required = False
    self.fields["hog1"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    self.field['hog1'].queryset = Submain.objects.filter(days__in__name="sunday")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.fields['hog1'].queryset = Submain.objects.filter(days__in=['id of dayname'])
```

And you may probably want to add .distinct().

Comment: i get error:
'DaysForm' object has no attribute 'field'
@cwhisperer

Comment: class Meta is missing where you define your fields: classMeta: model = 'yourmodel'     fields = ('name of field',)

Comment: i have it.
`
 self.field['hog1'].queryset = Submain.objects.filter(days__in=['1']).distinct()
class Meta:
        model = Day
        fields = '__all__'
`

Comment: self.field['hog1'] has a typo: s is missing

Comment: thank you,
but it wont filter.
look:
` self.fields['hog1'].queryset = Submain.objects.filter(days__in=['sunday']).distinct()`

Comment: ['sunday'] sunday should be replaced by the id